# How to know what 誰だって means in different contexts?

Tags: meaning

I'm having trouble understanding the meaning of  誰だって within different contexts;

> 誰だって楽な生活をしたい。
> Everybody wants to live in comfort.
>
> 誰だって 自尊心を 傷つけられるのは 嫌だ。
> Nobody wants his sense of worth to be damaged.

As such within these sentences 誰だって means either no one or anyone. What is changing the meaning in the sentence?

Comment: That difference is in English, not in Japanese.

Comment: Which of the two do you think is translated into “no one” and which “anyone”?

Comment: @aguijonazo How do you tell the difference then? is it just context?

Comment: I'm saying there is no difference.

Comment: 誰だって～は嫌だ means "everyone dislikes ～" simply because 誰だって means "everyone" and 嫌だ means "dislike". This shouldn't be difficult. It may be a habit of English speakers to paraphrase this as "no one wants to ～". If you speak English, you know when to do it to make the sentence look more natural.

Answer (score 4):

誰だって means "anyone" or "everyone" (or sometimes "whoever"). The literal translations would be:

> 誰だって楽な生活をしたい。
> Everyone wants to have an easy life.
>
> 誰だって自尊心を傷つけられるのは嫌だ。
> Everyone hates to have their pride damaged.

The latter sentence might sound more natural in English if you rephrased it like "No one wants to have ...", but that has nothing to do with how the original Japanese sentence is constructed.